# Geoserver's mosaic created out of 3 pictures, shows only 1 picture

Tags: geoserver, georeferencing, image-mosaic, world-file

I am trying to create mosaic in geoserver out of 3 jpg pictures.Every picture is accompanied by appropriate .jgw and prj file.
IMG_3293.jgw

```
0.0300000
0.00000000
0.00000000
-0.0300000
19.80492000
45.30164700
```

IMG_3298.jgw

```
0.0300000
0.00000000
0.00000000
-0.0300000
19.80416700
45.30286500
```

IMG_3299.jgw

```
0.0300000
0.00000000
0.00000000
-0.0300000
19.80431000
45.30321300
```

And i created .prj files for each picture as:
IMG_3293.prj

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator", 
  GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
  PROJECTION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","1024"]], 
  PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
```

And when i publish layer and go to preview it only thing i am shown is IMG_3298.jpg

I calculated that 1m is represented with 38 pixels and as i am using EPSG 3857 as native srs its default unit is 1m, pixel size is about 0.03m.
What might be the problem?

Comment: Do you have a chance to put your images somewhere for downloading?

Comment: Is this ok?                            
http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=1863c52   |                              
http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=5f28020    |                               
http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=5d6c220

Comment: your coordinates seem to be in WGS84 not 3857, so I suspect that the three images overlap at or around Null Island

Comment: I agree with @iant, with your numbers the footprints of the images overlap almost totally. How did you get the coordinates for the origin, for example `19.80492000 45.30164700`. Are they long-lat degrees? If I were you I would use for example QGIS georeferencer for measuring some ground control points.

Comment: yes those are long-lat degrees.
Well i tried georeferencing them in QGIS but i cant find some referent points which i can geotagg with enough accuracy because these are photos from the field and there aren't  buildings or bigger objects that i can recognize via google map.Is there some other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a coordinate system mismatch your projection file and the coordinates in the world file must be the same.

In this case you have told the tools reading the files that your projection is 3857 so the coordinates in the world file are to be read as metres, so this means that all three of your files are less than a millimetre apart so you can only see one of them.

The solution is to change the prj file to WGS84 and then use gdal_translate to reproject the files to epsg:3857 before you use them.